# Generic parameter vs polymorphic parameters

Tags: java

Suppose I have an interface

```
interface Car {
  void wroomWroom();
}
```

And bunch of classes that implement this interface.

```
class Mercedes implements Car {
  // implementation
}

class Volkswagen implements Car {
  // Implementation
}
```

In some place in the code I have two functions

```
// ...
bool checkCarsGeneric(List<? extends Car> cars) {
  System.out.println("Do generic checks");
  return true;
}

bool checkCarsByInterface(List<Car> cars) {
  System.out.println("Do generic checks");
  return true;
}
```

Both of these functions syntactically correct and, surprisingly, work correctly. In what cases I should prefer `List<? extends Car>` syntax over `List<Car>` syntax and why?

**UPD**

Invocation of these functions is follows:

```
List<Car> cars = Arrays.asList(
  new Mercedes(),
  new Volkswagen(),
  new Mercedes(),
  new Volkswagen()
);

checkCarsGeneric(cars);
checkCarsByInterface(cars);
```

Comment: You can't pass a `List<Mercedes>` where a `List<Car>` is required.

Comment: How can I disagree that associated question is similar?

Comment: Explain what you think is different about your case. The PECS discussion describes the conditions under which `? extends Car` is appropriate.

Comment: 1) PECS discussion is hard to find if you don't know what are you dealing with.
2) I was wondering if it does matter that `Car` is an interface and not a class. Maybe I didn't point it out well in the question.

Comment: I certainly understand that. That's the purpose of having the duplicate function, which is different from saying that the question is a bad one (downvoting or deleting); it helps direct future visitors who are thinking of the question in your terms to the larger discussion.

Comment: Ah. Lots of thanks then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the bytecode level, these two functions actually *are* identical.

The key difference is that, if you have a `List<Volkswagen>` somewhere in your code, you *can* pass it to the generic version, but if you pass it to the non-generic version, you get a compiler error (or at least warning).

On an unrelated sidenote, "Volkswagen" is one word and shouldn't get capitalized in the middle, and "Mercedes" is spelled with a "c".